# coauthoring with Office js code fails

Tags: office-js

Repro steps - 
create a Excel apps for office add-in with one button and containing following code

function getDataFromSelection()    {

```
    Word.run(function (context)    {

        var thisDocument = context.document;

        context.load(thisDocument, 'saved');

        return context.sync().then(function () {

            if (thisDocument.saved === false) {

                thisDocument.save();

                return context.sync().then(function () {

                    console.log('Saved the document');

                });
```

This works fine normally in normal situation.
BUT
If you open a document in Word Online in Editing Mode
Then you open the same document in Word UI (Edit in Word), enable your add-in and fire the button to run above code i.e. save the document through add-in, it fails with below error

Error: Upload failed This file is locked for editing by another user

If i save from Word UI, it works fine.

I am trying to understand why the save functionality is broken while doing coauthoring and trying to save from Office add-in.

Comment: In the first sentence, do you mean "Word" instead of Excel?  Looks like you have Word everywhere else...

Comment: Thanks Michael. Apologies, it was a typo, its Word only

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you meant Word, not Excel. And I was able to repro this issue. Its a bug, thanks for reporting this. We'll investigate in more detail and fix.

Comment: Thanks Juan. yes, i meant Word. I am very pleased with your quick response and you being able to repro it. I would be keen on hearing more on your investigation and any workaround, if possible.

Comment: as a follow up the bug was fixed, we are trying to include this fix on the update to be published around mid January next year. you can test it earlier if needed using the insiders updates.

Comment: Thanks a lot folks for your prompt action on this one!